# Words for "subsequent" and "following"

Tags: word-choice

Während meines Studiums habe ich solche Wörter oft gesehen (besonders in Mathematik):

```
aufeinanderfolgend
darauffolgend
nacheinanderfolgend
nachfolgend
```

Jedes bedeutet irgendwas wie "subsequent," "successive," oder "following" auf Englisch.  Ich vermute, dass jedes verschiedene Präzisionsniveaus bezüglich Reihenfolge oder der Chronologie einiger Ereignisse vermittelt.  Ich bin aber oft verwirrt, welches ich benutzen sollte.

Zum Beispiel, mit dem Satz

> Eine Addition von aufeinanderfolgenden absoluten Häufigkeiten führt
> zur Summenhäufigkeit.

könnte man ,,aufeinanderfolgend" mit einem der andere Wörter einsetzen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich sehe hier keine Alternative. Im Beispielsatz ist die Bedeutung *successive* gemeint und das wird nur durch *aufeinanderfolgend* abgebildet.

*Nacheinanderfolgend* habe ich noch nie gelesen, *darauffolgend* und *nachfolgend* sind zu ungenau, weil sie nur *irgendwie später* (auch im Sinne von "weiter unten im Text") bedeuten, aber die Qualität, dass kein Element ausgelassen werden darf, nicht transportieren.

Wie richtig kommentiert, ist *aufeinander* der wichtige Kern, im Sinne von *jedes folgt lückenlos seinem Vorgänger*. Auch *hintereinander* transportiert das m. E. nicht.

Comment: Also was wichtig ist, ist der "aufeinander"-Teil, oder?  Könnte "hintereinanderfolgend" eingesetzt wird?

Answer (score 1):

Wenn b auf a folgt, ist b das auf a folgende Objekt oder, wenn klar ist, dass wir uns auf a beziehen, das darauffolgende Objekt.

Dahingegen bezeichnet "einander" das Verhältnis mehrere Objekte zu einander (ach!), im Beispiel wären also a und b aufeinanderfolgend. Ebenso für "nacheinanderfolgend", nur dass es sich für mich weniger gut anhört.

"Nachfolgend" würde ich in dem Zusammenhang nicht benutzen.